# MVC razor syntax for accessing a static model member

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, static-members

For MVC razor, what is the syntax on the .cshtml page to access a static model member (variable),
for example,

```
@Html.DisplayFor(@(myNameSpace.myClass.myStaticVarName))
```

I did this after being warned by the auto-complete to use the type specifier instead of an instance element.

However, the above throws a run-time error:

Compiler Error Message: CS1646: Keyword, identifier, or string expected after verbatim specifier: @

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  Reminder to readers:  It's best *not* to use static variables in MVC unless you really have to, or your certain that they won't change from user-to-user.  A viable alternative is to use session variables instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use the template helpers (Display, DisplayFor, EditorFor, etc.) because they all have a hidden parameter which is the model given to the view.

To display just the value of the class variable, use `@myNameSpace.myClass.myStaticVarName`

Comment: This was IMHO the simplest way, but certainly thanks to everyone else who answered, and of course to Joe R Casey also!

Answer (score 2):

It's just assign it to a variable:

```
@{
var a = myNameSpace.myClass.myStaticVarName;
@Html.DisplayFor(m=> a)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If understood your question, Could it be "model.myStaticVarName"?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have 2 `@` on 1 line if the line starts with it. Remove the second `@`:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(myNameSpace.myClass.myStaticVarName)
```

Comment: It's not going to work. 
DisplayFor receives a Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> as argument.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee407390(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: The question isn't really concerned with the proper usage of DisplayFor (although you are correct). He wants to know how to access a static class member, and that is how.